# Do teaching an advance course helps in evaluation and tenure?

Tags: teaching, promotion

Do teaching an advance course helps in promotion or it does not matter?

Comment: Do you mean relative to not teaching at all or to teaching first-year undergraduate courses?

Comment: This is certainly a naive question, but it is inarguably natural, and touches on operational issues, I think, even if the asking is itself not particularly thought-through.

Comment: @schester relative to teaching first or second year courses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within my U.S. math department, teaching a successful, energetic, research-oriented graduate "topics" course is a plus inside the department. It is also essential, within the department, to have demonstrated "acceptable" capacity to teach bread-and-butter courses, such as ... calculus.

The engineering departments that determine the course of the "college of science and engineering" (due, I imagine, to the size of external grant funding... and the concommitant "overhead") view math, physics, and chemistry fundamentally as "service" departments, and, indeed, the *size* of these departments is hard to justify on any practical grounds except for the hordes of freshman and sophomores taking filtering/weeding/service courses. In any event, when tenure cases reach the "college" level, demonstrated success in teaching those lower-division courses is considered essential ... research success is taken for granted, and considered of mostly internal interest to the department, not to the college... and minimal involvement or non-involvement with lower-division teaching can ... upset... the engineering faculty.

So, at that level, it would be unwise to have *exclusively* done advanced teaching, even if "only" at an undergraduate level.

Within the department, it shows a certain kind of energy, I think, because it may well require more psychological effort to do the best job with higher-level material than to do an acceptable job with low-level material aided by a phalanx of teaching assistants. But there seems to be a watershed in preferences about teaching graduate courses, so new faculty preferences in that regard are mostly construed as a matter of taste or opinion, not essential.

Comment: Clarification: I'm at a large "state" university, perhaps one of the better, but still subject to a different political weather than privates, etc.